# What is the advantage of using @ParmDefinition in sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

```
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @name nvarchar(20)
SET @id = 5
SET @name = 'Paul'
```

What is the difference between these two options:

```
Set @SQLQueryInnen = 'SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE ID = ' + @id + ' AND NAME = ''' + @name + ''''
Execute sp_Executesql @SQLQueryInnen
```

and

```
Set @SQLQueryInnen = 'SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE ID = @id AND NAME = @name'
Set @ParmDefinition = '@id int, @name nvarchar(20)'
Execute sp_Executesql @SQLQueryInnen, @ParmDefinition, @id
```

So far I only see the overhad for declaring the data type of @id and @name twice, when using @ParmDefinition. On the other hand, the "string-building" seems a bit easier with @ParamDefinition.

Comment: The second one parameterized your query which helps to prevent SQL Injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You avoid having *stringly*-typed code - where you have to convert everything into a string so that you can shove it into the `@SQLQueryInnen` parameter, and then introduce issues because you have to work out how to safely and unambiguously perform the conversions to and from the strings back into the correct original data types.

For `int`s, the conversion issues aren't very apparent. But if you look at the number of issues people report (here, and on other forums) where they have issues converting between `datetime`s and strings, you'll realise that it does cause real issues. Best to keep the data as its natural type throughout.

Answer (score 4):

First case is SQL injection prone and a security risk. The discussion stops here.

Comment: ja, I heard the term before but never really tried to understand what it means, now I can see how dangerous it can get in the first case...

Answer (score 2):

I see no one mentioned one of the most important things. When you're using a parameterized query, your execution plans are cached.

Your query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable
WHERE ID = @id
    AND NAME = @name;
```

Its execution plan will be stored in memory and reused each time you query it (which is a great benefit). Meanwhile, if you're generating your code using string concatenation like that:

```
Set @SQLQueryInnen = 'SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE ID = ' + @id + ' AND NAME = ''' + @name + ''''
Execute sp_Executesql @SQLQueryInnen
```

Your code will generate an execution plan for each parameter combination (unless it's repeating) and the cached plan will not be reused. Imagine that you're passing `@Id = 1` and `@Name = 'Paul'`, Your generated query will look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable
WHERE ID = 5
    AND NAME = 'Paul';
```

If you change your name to `'Rob'`, your generated query will look like and SQL Server will have to create a new plan for it:

```
SELECT *
FROM someTable
WHERE ID = 5
    AND NAME = 'Rob';
```

Meaning plans won't be reused.  I hope it helps.

This is an article explaining this in a bit more detail: [EXEC vs. sp_executeSQL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/18/exec-vs-sp-executesql.aspx) (Don't rely on the article title, it explains the exact differences you asked in your question). Quote from it:

> The TSQL string is built only one time, after that every time same
> query is called with sp_executesql, SQL Server retrieves the query
> plan from the cache and reuse it