# sp_executesql Group by "must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

In a simplified version I'm trying to do something like that :

```
Set @datepart = 'DATEPART(year, myDate)' 
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT @datepart AS TIME 
                 FROM someTable 
                 GROUP BY @datepart'
Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery, N'@datepart nvarchar(1000)', @datepart
```

But I get :

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not
>   an outer reference.

It is working if I does not parameterize it, means

```
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT ' + @datepart + ' AS TIME 
                 FROM someTable 
                 GROUP BY ' + @datepart
Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using parametrized query you cannot achieve what you are trying to do only way is simple dynamic query

```
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT ' + @datepart + ' AS TIME 
                 FROM someTable 
                 GROUP BY ' + @datepart
Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

because the variable just act as value inside dynamic query. Consider the following example.

```
DECLARE @datepart NVARCHAR(1000),
        @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(max)

SET @datepart = 'DATEPART(year, getdate())'
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT @datepart AS TIME'

EXECUTE Sp_executesql
  @SQLQuery,
  N'@datepart nvarchar(1000)',
  @datepart
```

According to you the answer should be `2015` but the result is

```
DATEPART(year, getdate())
```

Answer (score 2):

What nobody else has quite realised is that you've asked a question and solved it yourself. SQL Server has quite rightly noted that you are trying to *group by* something, but report no outputs from it.

I took your query and made a version almost all of us should be able to use on SQL 2005+:

```
DECLARE  @datepart NVARCHAR(MAX), @SQLQUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
SEt @datepart  = 'DATEPART(year, myDate)' 
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT @datepart AS TIME 
                 FROM sys.objects 
                 GROUP BY @datepart'
Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery, N'@datepart nvarchar(1000)', @datepart
```

Now, this will blow up as expected. The reason being that @datepart is a *string* value. It's actually trying to:

SELECT 'String' FROM 'Table' GROUP BY 'String'

At no point does it actually need the table to answer that question. SQL throws it's arms up in confusion. What you need to do to achieve what you *seem* to be trying to do is simply concatenate the strings together, however inadvisable this might be:

```
DECLARE  @datepart NVARCHAR(MAX), @SQLQUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
SEt @datepart  = 'DATEPART(year, create_date)' 
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT ' + @datepart +' AS TIME 
                 FROM sys.objects 
                 GROUP BY '+ @datepart
Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Or in your specific case:

```
DECLARE  @datepart NVARCHAR(MAX), @SQLQUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
SEt @datepart  = 'DATEPART(year, myDate)' 
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT ' + @datepart +' AS TIME 
                 FROM someTable 
                 GROUP BY '+ @datepart
Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

If you commit code like this, I'd recommend typing up a resume though. This is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think simple select should do this job.
Query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(year,mydate) AS TIME 
FROM someTable
```

For a dynamic query:

```
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT DISTINCT' + @datepart + ' AS TIME 
                 FROM someTable'
Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Comment: it is not possible with parameters? I can't use a simple query in my use case and the second solution is - as I just learned - easy to exploit with SQLinjection and inperformant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670688/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-parmdefinition-in-sp-executesql

Answer (score 0):

if you `REPLACE` a query at run time with variable then you can achieve `2015`
dynamically

```
DECLARE @datepart NVARCHAR(100),
        @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(max)

SET @datepart = 'DATEPART(year, getdate())'
SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT @datepart AS TIME'

SET @SQLQuery    =   REPLACE(@SQLQuery, '@datepart', @datepart)
exec (@SQLQuery);
```

Comment: please check my answer to your replay, it is 1 comments above at the moment

Answer (score 0):

@tinka, this works fine. But I just tested with another example and it doesn't seem to help against SQLinjection. Maybe your solution is the same as using a normal concatenated query?

```
DECLARE @SQLQueryInnen nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ParameterDefinition nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @aufnr nvarchar(200)
SET @aufnr = '1234; SELECT * FROM sensitiveTable'-- here the attacker inserted an SQL Statement in aufnr


Set @SQLQueryInnen = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE aufnr = @aufnr'
Set @SQLQueryInnen = REPLACE(@SQLQueryInnen, '@aufnr', @aufnr)
Set @ParameterDefinition =  '@aufnr nvarchar(200)'
Execute sp_Executesql @SQLQueryInnen, @ParameterDefinition, @aufnr
-- Result: The illegal SELECT statement gets executed!!!
```

If I execute this example without the REPLACE, the attack won't work but you get: `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1234; SELECT * FROM qdb_tab_imp_me_q_fehler' to data type int.`