# sp_executesql date "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" in specific case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

I have something strange:

```
Declare @SQLQuery As nvarchar(Max)
Declare @maxdat date
Declare @dateColumn nvarchar(10)
Set @maxdat = GETDATE()
Set @dateColumn = 'ERDAT'
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE @dateColumn <= @maxdat'

Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery, N'@maxdat date, @dateColumn nvarchar(10)', @maxdat, @dateColumn
```

This will fail with `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

But the following will work just fine:

```
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ERDAT <= @maxdat'
```

Comment: because your comparison between two different data type so it is obvious

Comment: You cannot parameterize column *names* - parameters are for *values* - and you don't want to supply a string *value* on the left of that comparison, you want to supply a column *name*.

Comment: E.g. you say that `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ERDAT <= @maxdat` works fine but, of course, what you're attempting to do is closer to `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE 'ERDAT' <= @maxdat` - note the extra quote marks.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So the only possibility to achieve this if I still need this feature is `Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ' + @dateColumn + ' <= @maxdat'`?

Comment: `Declare @SQLQuery As nvarchar(Max)
Declare @maxdat date
Declare @dateColumn date
Set @maxdat = GETDATE()
Set @dateColumn = getdate()
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT 1 WHERE @dateColumn <= @maxdat'
Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery, N'@maxdat date, @dateColumn date', @maxdat, @dateColumn`

Comment: @tinka your comment should probably have be an answer. However it is wrong. Can't use *@datecolumn* as a parameter

Answer (score 2):

Try the updated code like this. Just put the @dateColumn parameter outside the query string

```
Declare @SQLQuery As nvarchar(Max)
Declare @maxdat date
Declare @dateColumn nvarchar(10)
Set @maxdat = GETDATE()
Set @dateColumn = 'ERDAT'
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ' + @dateColumn + ' <= @maxdat'

Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery, N'@maxdat date', @maxdat
```

Comment: Hi, yes that works, actually I come from that solution, but some guys explained me earlier why these string concats are not that good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670688/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-parmdefinition-in-sp-executesql

Comment: But since it's impossible with parameters I'll do it like that

Comment: The only thing I would add here is to wrap @dateColumn with QUOTENAME to help prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your dynamic SQL. the way you are doing it the variables will go as strings. You have to use the "+" symbol and do it like example below so that SQL can parse it and use 'variable value' instead of 'variable name'.

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS A
INTO 
#Temp

Declare @SQLQuery As nvarchar(Max)
Declare @maxdat date
Declare @dateColumn nvarchar(10)
Set @maxdat = DATEADD(Day,1,GETDATE())
Set @dateColumn = 'A'
--Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM #Temp WHERE @dateColumn >= @maxdat'
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM #Temp WHERE ' + @dateColumn + ' >= '+ CAST(@maxdat AS nvarchar(10))
--Print @SQLQuery
Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery, N'@maxdat date, @dateColumn nvarchar(10)', @maxdat, @dateColumn
```

Comment: hey, see comment above. Thanks for the reply, I'll do it with +